# Which function inside a loop is more efficient (ncol/nrow() or dim())

Tags: r, performance, loops, for-loop

In an exercise attempt I am trying to create a multiplication table using a for loop. I am new to programming and R is my first language that I learn, so I would like to know which functions inside loops are faster and more efficient. For now, I am not using methods of the apply family because I think that understanding of basic functions like the loops is important.

Here are two ways that I use to create a multiplicaton table:

Using `dim()` function:

```
mtx <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=10)

for(i in 1:dim(mtx)[1]){
  for(j in 1:dim(mtx)[2]){
    mtx[i,j] <- i*j
  }
}
```

Using `ncol`/`nrow()` function:

```
mtx <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=10)

for(i in 1:ncol(mtx)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(mtx)){
    mtx[i,j] <- i*j
  }
}
```

Which way is more efficient and generaly better to use?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried timing them? Also, have you looked at the code for, say `ncol`?

Comment: Hello A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 , thank you for the quick reply. I tried to type ncol without the parenthesis into my console and see that it uses `dim(x)[2L]`. Does it mean that both funtions are same in matter of speed?

Comment: I tried to time both function with a matrix with 10000 colums/rows. The ´ncol()´ approach takes ages to run, or my computer has a problem.

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong parts of the code if you are interested in efficiency. You should learn to profile code. And of course, you should not use a loop for this.

Comment: I'd use `(1:rows) %*% t(1:cols)`

Comment: or rather `tcrossprod(1:rows, 1:cols)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the functions like you do in your example, the difference is really neglectable. This is because the functions get called only once per loop definition (and not every loop iteration!)

I would definitely prefer `ncol`/`nrow` because its much easier too read than `dim(x)[1]`.

That being said, if you just go for the timings, the `dim` function is faster than `ncol`/`nrow`. If you look at the source code, you can see that `ncol` is implemented as

```
function (x) 
dim(x)[2L]
```

which means that `ncol` calls `dim` and is therefore marginally slower.

If you really want to save some speed with big matrices I would suggest to create the loop vectors beforehand like this:

```
rows <- 1:nrow(mtx)
cols <- 1:ncols(mtx)
for (i in rows) {
    for (j in cols) {
        mtx[i, j] <- i * j    
    }
}
```

Comment: This is likely to be pretty much the same speed as the original. For a real speedup, try `outer(1:rows, 1:cols, "*")`

Comment: For small matrices it is indeed very similar. However if you have a matrix with lots of columns the original version would allocate memory for the vector `1:ncol(mtx)` again and again for every row which can be slow! Your version is of course faster anyway, but OP said he wanted to learn `for`-loops.

Comment: Yes, microbenchmark shows a ~50% speedup when using a matrix with 50 rows and 1000000 columns.

Comment: @AEF and now compare with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903707/which-function-inside-a-loop-is-more-efficient-ncol-nrow-or-dim/42904111?noredirect=1#comment72907866_42903707). If OP complains about R freezing, a 50 % speed-up won't help him.

Comment: @Roland, yes I am fully aware that there are much faster solutions and I agree that your solution is definitely better in any real world setting. However OP specifically mentioned that he wanted to learn and understand `for`-loops.

Comment: Yes, but they are working on a false premise: In R, it is less important to understand `for` loops than to understand vectorization, matrix algebra etc. And trying to optimize efficiency of a `for` loop for this task is just wasted effort.